# Jquery remove effect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any way to remove effect for `xxxx` element?

For example, when I do this:

```
$('#xxxx').effect( "bounce",{times:3,distance:20},1000);
```

and use a setTimeout for display/hide this element - there is problem with bounce effect. When I move very fast on element that calls this effect and start `setTimeout` method - I think that bounce effect block timer and do not let setTimeout` to finish.

I don't want to `stop()` effect/animation, i need something that will remove it when mouse leave button.

Comment: You are missing a closing ' after: #xxxx

Comment: Provide us with something more, like a Fiddle example/comprehensive snippets, so it clarifies what you're after.

Comment: it's to much to write. Can You just tell me is there any method to remove effect? Something like .remove_effect() ?